# Proguard setting to not remove unused method

Tags: android, proguard

Conside the following code structure for android:

```
package blah;
class A{
    class B{
        public void foo(String s){
        }
    } 
}
```

How can I tell proguard to not remove or obfuscate foo.
foo is unused function in code at compile time but is run at run-time from another code.

I have tried:

```
-keep class blah.A.B;

-keepclassmembers class blah.A.B {
  public void foo(String s);
}
```

etc. but nothing stops Proguard from removing that function.
I do not want proguard to change name of 'foo'. Proguard may change the name of class A or class B but not the function name 'foo'.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost right. In java bytecode, the $ character separates the names of inner classes and their outer classes (to avoid ambiguities with package names). So, to keep just the method:

```
-keepclassmembers class blah.A$B {
  public void foo(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: to avoid ambiguities with package names... oh, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a method 'myClickHandler' referenced only in an xml file.

This

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void myClickHandler(android.view.View );
}
```

stops it being removed in my application. Perhaps the extends .. will work for you