# Method in inner class stripped away by proguard

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, proguard

I'm currently working on an Android project, in which I'm doing some calculation in C, using Android NDK.

My application works fine as long as I do not run proguard, but when I do, a method "reportProgress", is stripped away by proguard. The method is part of a private inner class that extends AsyncTask

```
private class CalculateTask extends AsyncTask
```

I call my native code with a reference to the CalculateTask instance. The native code then call a member in this class, using the following code in JNI

```
jclass taskClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, task);
jmethodID reportProgressMid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, taskClass, "reportProgress", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z");
```

where task is the reference to the instance of CalculateTask. I'm having a hard time telling proguard not to strip away the

```
public boolean reportProgress(String, int)
```

method, which is only called via JNI.

Until now I have taken the following approaches, none of which did the trick:

Keeping the entire class:

```
-keep class MYPACKAGENAME.CalculateScreen$CalculateTask
```

Only keeping the mentioned method, by doing:

```
-keep class MYPACKAGENAME.CalculateScreen$CalculateTask {
    public boolean reportProgress(java.lang.String,int);
}
```

Or this:

```
-keepclassmembers class MYPACKAGENAME.CalculateScreen$CalculateTask {
    public boolean reportProgress(java.lang.String,int);
}
```

Using annotations (reusing a Google AdMob annotation):

```
-keep class MYPACKAGENAME.CalculateScreen$CalculateTask {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName <methods>;
}
```

Or this:

```
-keepclassmembers class MYPACKAGENAME.CalculateScreen$CalculateTask {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName <methods>;
}
```

My proguard configuration is based on the "optimize" distributed with Android SDK, named proguard-android-optimize.txt.

Please note that proguard is run via Gradle, and I have made sure that the proguard task is cleaned and rerun.

Comment: Somewhat corresponds to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298992/proguard-setting-to-not-remove-unused-method/9302402#9302402
But I don't see how my approach #3 differ from the proposed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second and third configuration should work for this case:

```
-keepclassmembers class MYPACKAGENAME.CalculateScreen$CalculateTask {
    public boolean reportProgress(java.lang.String,int);
}
```

You should check the class name and method name for typos. You should also check if the method really is public.

You can verify if the method is preserved in `bin/proguard/seeds.txt`.

You can also check the compiled input class and the processed output class with `javap`.

Comment: The suggested approach, was indeed the right approach. Thank you for your quick reply, Eric.